# Display embed images in Flash/Flex Builder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flexbuilder, embedding, flash-builder

i'm using image embedding in Flex 4 (the same goes with Flex 3). I have one class with a lot of

```
[Embed(source="../assets/icons/icon1.png")] 
public static const image:ClasS
```

And i reference them using:

```
<mx:Image source="{imagesResources.image}"/>
```

When i run the application i see the icon but in Flash(Flex) Builder i can't see the images while working in Design mode. Is there any way to enable image visualization in Flash Builder design mode ? or a better way to include resources.

thanks

Comment: Will these icons ever change ? That,is are you fine if they are bundled into a custom component
`<mx:imageResourcesimage />`

Comment: Well we can change the images sometimes during development but i don't think that they will change often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly no. If you embed an image (or resource) and then set the source property to be the Class variable they will not show in Design View in Flex Builder for Flash Builder.

What I do when I want to see them is make them static source="mypath/myimage.jpg", do the tweaks then change that back to the Class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the @Embed() directive in MXML?  Look at [this link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_3.html) under the title "Using the @Embed() directive in MXML"